# For Loop to iterate of Class list attribute

Tags: python, oop, for-loop

I'm new to object orientated programming in Python and have hit a snag. I'm trying to iterate over a class's list attribute however my loop prints the whole list not each item.

Class:

```
class Population:
    def __init__(self, population):
        self.population = population
        self.popList = []
        pool = ThreadPool(mp.cpu_count()-1)
        self.popList.append([pool.apply(Creature.P, args=(
            self, 0, random.randint(1, 2))) for creature in range(population)])
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import doctest
        doctest.testmod()
```

First call (which accurately creates the population and popList):

```
 # RANDOM FIRST GENERATION INITIALIZATION
    pop = Population(population)
```

Then calling this:

```
for x in pop.popList:
    print(x)
```

However in this instance `x` is the entire `popList` and not the single item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
self.popList.append([pool.apply(Creature.P, args=(self, 0, random.randint(1, 2)))
                     for creature in range(population)])
```

Should be like this:

```
self.popList = [pool.apply(Creature.P, args=(self, 0, random.randint(1, 2)))
                for creature in range(population)]
```

You are appending a list to your `popList`, so you're making it be a list with one list in it, and that inner list has all of the population.

So `popList` in your original code will end up looking like this: `[[Creature, Creature, Creature]]`

When you actually want to have it just be a list of Creatures: `[Creature, Creature, Creature]`